# Removing third element from list until there are less than 3 numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a problem. I need to create a list . And in every iteration i need to remove the third element and print the list without the deleted element.

The thing is. I'm trying to do an algorithm of deleting the third element without remove function or other inbuilt list functions. In my code I covered the following possibilities. If my list has less than 3 elements I print a message saying the list is short. If my list has 3 elements in it I will assign the third element the value of the second element and so on. My problem is when my list has more than 3 elements.

```
v=[]   # list of numbers the user inputs
two=[] #list with only 2 elements
vector=[] # list with third element deleted when len(v)>3

def create_array():
    n=int(input('Digit total elements in dynamic array - '))
    for i in range(0,n):
        element=int(input('Digit element to array - '))
        v.append(element)
    return v
print(create_array())

def remove_third_element():
    for j in range(0,len(v)):
        if len(v)<3:  # if number of elements in list < 3 there is no element to delete
            print('There is no element do delete! ')
            return 0
        elif len(v)==3:
            v[2]==v[1] and v[1]==v[0]
            two=[v[0],v[1]]
            return two
        else:
            v[0]==v[1] and v[1]==v[2]

print(remove_third_element())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elif len(v) > 3:
   ret = [];
   for i in range(len(v)):
      if(i != 2) ret.append(v[i]);
   return ret
```

should do the trick

By the way, with this method you can remove you elif len(v) == 3

Also your code :

```
elif len(v)==3:
        v[2]==v[1] and v[1]==v[0]
        two=[v[0],v[1]]
        return two
```

won't work because '==' is used as condition in python so it will return a boolean and not assign value. 
go for

```
v[2] = v[1]
v[1] = v[0]
```

instead

Comment: what is the ret for ?

Comment: ret is an array, the same as the "two" you return when the length is 3

Comment: so you will apend every element except the element in position 2 . I think i get it thanks

Comment: if i put v[2]=v[1]

Comment: and v[1]=v[0]   it return equal values for all positions

Comment: if you have v = [10, 12, 3] at the end you'll have v = [10,10,12] and there you return [v[1],v[2]]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Pythonic way of making a new list without the original list's third element.

```
new_list = old_list[:2] + old_list[3:]
```

`old_list[:2]` is shorthand for "until the 2-th index" (so we'll get index 0 and 1) of the `old_list`.

`old_list[3:]` is shorthand for, "from 3rd index 'til the end" (so index 3, 4, etc.).

Both return lists; in python, if you add lists, concatenation actually happens.

---

As an example, if `old_list = [1,2,3,4,5]`, then `new_list[:2]` will be `[1,2]` and `new_list[3:]` will be `[4,5]`. So combining that will be `[1,2,4,5]`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this statement: `v[2]==v[1] and v[1]==v[0]` won't assign values!
Operation `==` return boolean.

Lets say your `v` looks like this: `v = [1, 1, 3]`. 
Then `v[2]==v[1] and v[1]==v[0]` gives you result: `False and True`, and this gives you reulst `False`. You can check it if you print this `print(v[2]==v[1] and v[1]==v[0])`.

If you want to assign values, you can use a statement like this: `v[2], v[1] = v[1], v[0]`.

Comment: but that type of statement is not for switching positions?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you don't want to switch position, then I am not sure what you want to do. Could you explain what you wanted to achieve with this statement?

Comment: i wanted to assign the value in position two to position one

Comment: Basically `v[2], v[1] = v[1], v[0] ` do same what: `v[2] = v[1], v[1] = v[0]`. Example:
`v = [3, 5, 7]`, then after operation `v[2], v[1] = v[1], v[0]` you have: `v = [3, 3, 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def main():
    big_list = [ x for x in range(20) ]
    while len(big_list) > 3:
        big_list =  big_list[:2] +  big_list[3:]
    print(big_list)
```